# I can't solve this problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{(k + 1) (k + 3)}{(k + 2) ^ 2})$$

The answer is = ln(2/3)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. This site is intended to discuss _Wolfram Mathematica_ software. If you are looking for a mathematical, pen and paper explanation of how to calculate this sum, please refer to the [Mathematic**s** StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Worst title ever.  Please rewrite to refer to the *content* of your question.  Also, this is the wrong site for a math question unrelated to *Mathematica* software.

Comment: `Sum[Log[(k + 1) (k + 3)/(k + 2)^2], {k, 1, Infinity}]  `does the job nicely.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not sure about that - it is certainly honest.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Indeed, not the right site. Anyways, if you want to compute the series yourself, then recall that $\ln( \frac{a \, b}{c \, d}) = \ln(a) + \ln(b) - \ln(c)- \ln(d)$. Use this to expand the summand. And then have a look how each summand interacts with its neighbors...

Comment: It's a telescoping product:  $\sum \ln f(k) = \ln  \prod f(k) = \frac{(1+1)(1+4)(2+1)(2+4)(3+1)(3+4)\cdots}{(1+2)^2 (2+2)^2 (3+2)^2 \cdots} = \ln \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots}{3^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 6^2 \cdots} = \ln \frac{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 6^2 \cdots}{3^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 6^2 \cdots} = \ln \frac{2}{3}.$

Comment: *Can you please help me?* Did you try anything?

Comment: "Not sure about that?!"  Are you kidding?  Your title could apply to every problem in calculus, or number theory, or topology, or complex analysis, or...  Honest?  What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sum[Log[((k + 1)*(k + 3))/(k + 2)^2], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

yields -Log[3/2] or Log[2/3] or Log[2]-Log[3].

That is what Wolfram Mathematica and WolframAlpha do.

Of course, I may have missed something.